# Android: Managing projects in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I developed pretty large Paid app for Android. It has many sections and plenty of images and videos. Now, I want to create a LITE version which will have only few section available (with some disabled functions and changed UI) and only some images and videos (80% less resources than the Paid version).

My question to you guys is what would be the best way to handle this problem. Obviously, I can just copy the project and remove unnecessary sections,resources, etc. However, it will make the project hard to maintain (for every bug I would have to fix two project independently). I know that in XCode for iPhone you can set targets and specify which resources can be disabled. Is there anything similar in Eclips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with this earlier, because I also had a paid/free combination on a couple of apps and the manual process seemed too tedious.

I created a workspace with three projects
1. A library project with all the common code and resources
2. Free version
3. Paid version

All you have to do in the actual installable projects is register the activities.  They can live in the common library project, but you just have to register them with fully qualified names in your app projects' manifests (same goes with a custom application class if you use one).

You can use the PackageManager to determine the fully qualified name of the running app and turn functionality on or off.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but after doing some more research it looks like it's the most appropriate way of handling different versions of the app.